# Dart - Validación de futures anidados

Tags: firebase, dart

tengo este futuro que devuelve un entero si es necesario.

Las condiciones para dar de alta un nuevo usuario son:

- No puede existir el mismo usuario con el mismo documento y tipo de documento.
- No puede existir el mismo usuario con el mismo número de teléfono.
- No puede existir el mismo usuario con el mismo mango.

Mi función funciona como se espera pero no estoy satisfecho con el resultado. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo mejorar este código?

```
Future<int> createUserWithFirebase(
    UserModel _user,
  ) async {
    int code = 1;

    final User? _userAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    QuerySnapshot userExistsDocument = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('document', isEqualTo: _user.document)
        .where('typeDocument', isEqualTo: _user.typeDocument)
        .get();

    QuerySnapshot userExistsPhone = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('phone', isEqualTo: _user.phone)
        .get();

    QuerySnapshot userExistsMac = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('uidHandle', isEqualTo: _user.uid)
        .get();

    QuerySnapshot handleExists = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('handles')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: _user.uidHandle)
        .get();

    if (userExistsDocument.docs.isEmpty &&
        userExistsPhone.docs.isEmpty &&
        handleExists.docs.isNotEmpty &&
        userExistsMac.docs.isEmpty) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(_userAuth!.uid)
          .update(_user.toJson());

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('handles')
          .doc(_user.uidHandle)
          .update({'uidUser': _userAuth.uid});
    } else {
      if (userExistsDocument.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        code = 2;
      } else if (userExistsPhone.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        code = 3;
      } else if (handleExists.docs.isEmpty) {
        code = 4;
      } else if (userExistsMac.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        code = 5;
      }
    }

    return code;
  }
```

Comment: Muchos no podemos ver la imagen, intenta poner código

Comment: Hola @JonathanPerez, corregido, gracias.

Comment: la verdad es que me di la pela de escribir el código, solo porque tenía tiempo y quise analizar todo el código

Answer (score 1):

Mas bien sería optimización de procesos, porque haces varias peticiones a tu Firebase secuencialmente y creería yo, que según las restricciones que especificas, deberian depender del resultado anterior cada query que ejecutas.

Esto hará que el consumo hacia tu firebase se pueda reducir y así aprovechar mejor los planes que ofrece firebase.

Comparto una idea, optimizacion consumos innecesarios, reservas de memoria y se centraliza

```
Future<int> createWithFirebase(
    UserModel _user
) async {

    final User? _userAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    // userExistDocument
    QuerySnapshot qs = await service('users', 'document', _user.document, 'typeDocument', _user.typeDocument).get();

    if (qs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        return 2;
    }

    // userExistPhone
    qs = await service('users', 'phone', _user.phone).get();

    if (qs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        return 3;
    }

    // handleExist
    qs = await service('handles', 'uid', _user.uidHandle).get();

    if (qs.docs.isEmpty) {
        return 4;
    }

    // userExistMac
    qs = await service('users', 'uidHandle', _user.uid).get();

    if (qs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        return 5;
    }

    update(_userAuth, _user);

    return 1;
}

QuerySnapshot service = (String collection, String param1, String value1, String param2 = null, String value2 = null) => {
    if (param2 !== null && value2 !== null) {
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(collection)
            .where(param1, isEqualTo: value1)
            .where(param2, isEqualTo: value2).get();
    } else {
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(collection)
            .where(param1, isEqualTo: value1).get();
    }
};

update(User _userAuth, UserModel _user) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(_userAuth!.uid)
        .update(_user.toJson());

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(_user.uidHandle)
        .update({ 'uidUser': _userAuth.uid });
}
```

Saludos,

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Hice hace poco algo parecido a esto, gracias...

Comment: La verdad, no he llegado a interactuar aun con Flutter, así que me demoré un poco en responder por ello. jejejje